# Why does a flyback converter in DCM mode have a different oscillation waveform at start and end of MOSFET turn off?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, flyback

[image]

As seen from the waveform, when the MOSFET turns off, it has some high-frequency oscillations (shown in red) whereas before MOSFET turns on it has low-frequency oscillations. I have found that the oscillation during turn-off is due to parasitic Cgd and the transformer's leakage inductance and that oscillation before turn-on is due to parasitic Cgd and primary inductance.

Why does this primary inductance not participate during turn off or why does the leakage inductance not participate in oscillation before turning on? There is only one coupled inductor, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Why does this primary inductance not participate during turn off or
> why does the leakage inductance not participate in oscillation before
> turning on? There is only one coupled inductor, right?*

[image]

Image from [here](http://www.stades.co.uk/Flyback/flyback%20DCM2.html) shown for clarity.

When the MOSFET turns off, most of the energy stored in the primary winding transfers into the secondary winding but, some of the energy is not. This is due to an imperfect magnetic coupling between primary and secondary coils. So then we talk about the primary inductance being made from two series inductors; the main part that couples to the secondary and, the lesser part that we call "leakage inductance".

That leakage inductance might be 2 or 3 percent of the overall primary inductance.

So, when the MOSFET turns off, a small amount of uncoupled energy is rapidly released and resonates with the MOSFET drain-source capacitance. And, because the leakage inductance is a fraction of the value of the overall primary inductance it has a high resonant frequency.

But, you might say, if the leakage inductance is in series with the coupled inductance then how-come the net inductance is so small at that moment in time? The answer is because the coupled inductance (secondary) acts like a voltage source when energy is transferring. It acts like a voltage source because of regular transformer action; the secondary is producing a DC voltage (as we want) and, that DC voltage reflects back to the primary via the coupled part of the primary inductance. Hence the net inductance seen at the primary during this period is only leakage inductance.

---

When there is insufficient energy left to push through the output diode into the DC storage capacitor, a resonant circuit is formed again involving the drain-source capacitance and primary inductance hence, the frequency is much lower this time because the whole of the primary inductance is involved.

[image]

There are a few subtleties that slightly paint a more complex picture but I find there's no benefit in discussing them or evaluating them for most flyback circuits.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Andy

Comment: @ArunKumarThawait please take the [2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to enlighten yourself on giving thanks.

Comment: @Andyaka the tour should be mandatory for all users.

Comment: @RohatKılıç it should be but, is it actually?

Comment: the problem I feel is that I can give an accepted mark to only one answer but In most cases, multiple people's answers together solve the problem

Comment: @ArunKumarThawait yes, hence the votes system. You can accept only one answer (i.e. the one fits best to your needs), and you can upvote the others.

Comment: @Andyaka probably not. Could be like a reminder for all the members but should be mandatory for especially newcomers -- maybe they shouldn't be allowed to post a question without tour completion *(No I'm not suggesting a completion test)* :) There are lots of answered but open questions already. Community Bot pumps tens of them to the homepage everyday.

Comment: @ArunKumarThawait Nobody will be on your back in these circumstances. You should choose an answer to accept (if you have an answer to your problem) but, if you want to choose one of the others then I'll understand.

Comment: @RohatKılıç it's a meta discussion really.

Answer (score 3):

In addition what Tim says in his answer which is absolutely correct, I'd like to remind you that in CCM the primary winding **is not** allowed to reset (the stored energy will be partially transferred to the load), so that's why you don't see the low-frequency ringing. In DCM, the magnetising inductance is allowed to reset fully and also there'll be some enough dead time to resonate with leakage inductance and parasitic capacitance *(That low-frequency oscillation's frequency is determined by the parasitic capacitance and the sum of magnetising and leakage inductances)*.

While the primary switch is on (energy storage process) both the leakage and the primary magnetising inductances (or their magnetic fields) store energy. When you turn the primary switch off, the stored energy in magnetising inductance (or its magnetic field) will be transferred to the secondary. And the leakage inductance has no contribution to the energy transfer. So, during the transfer, the leakage inductance will be busy with resonating with the parasitic capacitance.

Comment: Now I got what Mr. Tim was saying. Thanks

Comment: Good note -- free ringdown is optional, it depends on operating condition (CCM/DCM). Indeed, it can even be useful, as in BCM quasi-resonant designs: by switching on during a valley, Coss is partially or even fully discharged already, saving switching loss.

Answer (score 2):

Draw out the circuit and note which components are on and off (transistor and diode) during which phases.  Then simplify the equivalent circuit for each phase:

- While transistor is on, it becomes an effective short circuit; and the diode is off, an effective capacitance.  Ringing will be observed at the secondary side, determined by C<sub>JO</sub> and transformer LL.
- While transistor is off and diode is on, the diode becomes an effective short circuit; and the transistor is off, an effective capacitance.  Ringing will be observed at the primary side, determined by C<sub>oss</sub> and transformer LL.
- While both are off, both capacitances add, any remaining energy between them quickly equalizes (i.e. the mode consisting of both capacitances, and transformer LL, in series), and they ring down with magnetizing inductance (primary and secondary together, or in whatever pri/sec/whatever referred perspective you wish to simplify it into).

Damping these ringing waveforms can indeed require up to three snubbers, one each corresponding to the respective phases of operation.  The high-frequency resonances have a low impedance (\$Z_0 = \sqrt{\frac{LL}{C_{oss}}}\$ (or \$C_{JO}\$)) so take a noticeably different RC value than free ringdown (Lp >> LL, most of the time).  Some simplification may be possible, like covering primary turn-off and free ringdown conditions with an RCD (dV/dt, rate) snubber; or, sometimes enough loss can be had by, say, adding a ferrite bead on the diode lead, to dampen the secondary ringing without having to add more components.

For a basic RC snubber, choose R = Z<sub>0</sub> and \$C \ge 2.5 C_{oss}\$ (or \$C_{JO}\$).

Comment: That first statement of your answer ( "Draw out the circuit and note which components are on and off (transistor and diode) during which phases. Then simplify the equivalent circuit for each phase" ) was most helpful. Thanks